# SonarQube : SonarQube server can not be reached

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm new to SonarQube. I would like to implement SonarQube with Jenkins on my software factory. Before I started I read a artikel on the internet how to implement SonarQube with Jenkins (book DevOps).

See pictures below:
1. First, I created on SonarQube a Token on pasted it into Jenkins --> Server authentication token
[image: Jenkins > Server authentication token]

2. Setup SonarQube Scanner
   [image: Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration]
3. Build configuration on Jenkins Job. 
   [image: Jenkins build configuration Job]

When I rebuild my project on Jenkins, I got the follow Error: SonarQube server [URL] can not be reached

[image: Error Message Build]

When I clicked on the URL message, my browser will redirected me to SonarQube page

Can anybody help me with my problem?

Kind regards 
Michael

Comment: You've established that your machine can get to your SonarQube instance. You have not established that your Jenkins box can get there. This sounds like some sort of network issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should verify your firewall, on which operating system did you install SonarQube? In most systems, port 9000 is not open and it is a common source of failure.